# SOAP uploading service using C#/Wcf

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I need to create a SOAP service that accepts a document of certain kind. The document has XSD schema and such. However, a service that accepts that document (I need to  re-create an existing service) provides the following call template (URL removed from xmlns):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="url">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <p:upload>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:sender>?</p:sender>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:type>?</p:type>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:data>cid:1376273768452</p:data>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:version>?</p:version>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:filename>?</p:filename>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:deliveryDate>?</p:deliveryDate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <p:messageId>?</p:messageId>
        </p:upload>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please advice me what sort of request is that (I suspect some upload request with an attachment) and how possibly I can upload a given document using this format; how I can create such a service using C#/ WCF. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: It's a SOAP 1.1 message.  Create a WCF Application project in Visual Studio - out of the box it will use `basicHttpBinding` which is SOAP 1.1.  The actual implementation of the service contract will depend on what your requirements are.  It looks like metadata describing a file that was uploaded.

Comment: Yes, I have got that and I do have a SOAP service done. But I wonder if this contract is CUSTOM or it is a standard contracr for some file uploading mechanism.